# More than one file was found with OS independent path 'builddef.lst' error while build

Tags: android, gradle

please tell me what is the problem  I saw same question in stack overflow but didn't solved my problem ...the error appears when I implement **implementation project(':videocompressor')** to my gradle please guys I don't know much about this please help me

**this is my app.gradle**

```
android {
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.alpha.lapid"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    renderscriptTargetApi 27
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    lintOptions {
        disable 'RestrictedApi'
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

}
buildTypes {
    release {

        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
}
productFlavors {
}
}
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:15.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.github.ittianyu:BottomNavigationViewEx:1.2.4'
implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.4'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
implementation 'br.com.simplepass:loading-button-android:1.7.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.yanzhenjie:mediascanner:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
implementation 'com.github.jd-alexander:LikeButton:0.2.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:15.2.0'
implementation 'com.allattentionhere:autoplayvideos:0.2.0'
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.3.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.+'
implementation 'me.shaohui:bottomdialog:1.1.9'
implementation 'com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.1.21'
implementation 'com.allattentionhere:autoplayvideos:0.2.0'
implementation 'im.ene.toro3:toro:3.4.2'
implementation 'im.ene.toro3:toro-ext-exoplayer:3.4.2'
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:15.0.0'
implementation project(':videocompressor')
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
   apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

**this is my library gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
implementation files('libs/isoparser-1.0.6.jar')
implementation files('libs/aspectjrt-1.7.3.jar')
}
```